# PHP variable gets overwritten in foreeach loop with last item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, foreach

I've looked at other "PHP variable overwritten" answers and still can't figure this out.

I'm using this PHP to get all the product category slugs on a single product page:

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
if(is_array($terms)){
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $product_cat_slug = $term->slug;
    $product_cat_slugs = ' product_cat-' . $product_cat_slug;
    echo $product_cat_slugs;
}
}
```

The line `echo $product_cat_slugs;` outputs `product_cat-category1 product_cat-category2`.

The problem is that when I delete the `echo $product_cat_slugs;` from the function above and use `<?php echo $product_cat_slugs; ?>` elsewhere on the page, all I get for output is the last category slug `product_cat-category2`, and not both categories `product_cat-category1 product_cat-category2`.

What's wrong? `$product_cat_slugs` seems to be overwritten when outside the foreach; how can I prevent that?

How do I output `product_cat-category1 product_cat-category2` outside of the loop?

Comment: Yes, you are overwriting it inside of the loop. What else did you think `$product_cat_slugs = ' product_cat-' . $product_cat_slug;` was going to do? Decide how you want to save all of the results, such as putting them all in an array or appending to an existing string.

Comment: I want them to all output like `product_cat-category1 product_cat-category2` using echo `$product_cat_slugs;` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might I suggest to append the string, such as

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

if( is_array( $terms ) ) {
    $product_cat_slugs = ''; //Define the variable outside of the loop
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $product_cat_slugs .= ' product_cat-' . $term->slug; //Append the slug onto the string that already exists
    }
    echo $product_cat_slugs; //Echo the string outside of the loop so it only occurs once.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I see how the slug is appended to the string. All the other seemingly similar answers used different methods.